# What was the reason for Job's original success and prosperity?

Tags: theology, reward-punishment, job-iyov-book-of

The book starts with the description of Job's piety and then his wealth and success:

> ... That man was blameless and upright; he feared God and shunned evil. Seven sons and three daughters were born to him; his possessions were seven thousand sheep, three thousand camels, five hundred yoke of oxen and five hundred she-asses, and a very large household. That man was wealthier than anyone in the East. [Job.1.2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Job.1.2?lang=en&with=Malbim&lang2=en)

Does this order hint at the fact that his success was caused by his piety or does the book eventually teach the lack of connection?

Comment: Thinking out loud I would assume it was because they went hand in hand i.e. his wealth was inextricably linked with his piety, There are numerous sources that point to the numerous chasodim that he did with his wealth in order to benefit others.

Comment: Abraham was blessed with wealth because of his piety. Can w assume the same happened to Job?